# Entering text with a capital letter in webview Flutter. How can I implement this?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a Flutter project.
When working with a specific widget, I want that when entering text in webview flutter, the user's text input on the on-screen keyboard starts with a capital letter. How can I achieve the result I need?
Important: the text should not change automatically, it is necessary that the user can configure it independently. But at the same time, the initial appearance of the on-screen keyboard should consist of capital letters.
I also want this to apply to all fields of the same html class.
[image]

**my code**

```
import 'package:beamer/beamer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import '../../../../../../app/app.dart';
import '../../widgets/widgets.dart';

class SignUpWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpWebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpWebView> createState() => _SignUpWebViewState();
}

class _SignUpWebViewState extends State<SignUpWebView> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;

  bool _isLoading = true;

  void _transfer(String url) {
    final link = url.replaceFirst(
      'openid-connect/auth',
      'openid-connect/registrations',
    );
    _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(link));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..enableZoom(false)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(
              'https://test.com',
            )) {
              _transfer(url);
            }
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(
              'https://test.com',
            )) {
              _controller.runJavaScript('''
              var inputsField = document.getElementsByClassName('text-field__input');
              for (var i = 0; i < inputsField.length; i++) {
                inputsField[i].setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'sentences');
                  inputsField[i].style.appearance="textfield"
              }
              ''');
              setState(() {
                _isLoading = false;
              });
            }
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith(
              'https://test.com',
            )) {
              context.beamToNamed(SignInLocation.signInPath);
            }
            if (request.url.startsWith(
              'https://google.com',
            )) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://test.com'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.bgContrast,
      appBar: const SignUpAppBar(),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : SafeArea(
              child: WebViewWidget(
                controller: _controller,
                layoutDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}

``
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextCapitalization.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add this property to your TextField, and it will solve your issue

```
TextField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
...
```

Since your view is based on the **Web** (**HTML** and **JS**), one solution I see is to use **JavaScript** to find the field in the webpage and create an event to force the camelcase on the input like this:

```
var object = document.getElementById("elementID"); // your element on the Webpage
object.oninput = function(e) { 
word = e.target.value; 
e.target.value = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
```

};

You can replace the `getElementById` with any other query function, to make sure the element is selected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question.
I need the text not to change automatically, and the user can customize it independently. But at the same time, the initial appearance of the on-screen keyboard should consist of capital letters.
At the same time, I found this problem on an iOS device

Comment: I've changed my answer, use this property to make your input start with a capital letter.

Comment: I don't quite understand what TextField has to do with it 
The field is located in the webview interface and not in the flutter application. I didn't create separate input fields by-by webview

Comment: I couldn't tell from your first post, that you were using a webview. The most probable solution is to actually use JavaScript directly on the page. Notice this implies you don't have direct access to the page code. but you can run scripts over it